# How to fix CROSS SITE origin frames issues through COLDFUSION

Tags: iframe, coldfusion, frameset

I was created the "Test.cfm" page and split by frameset. Here, I have tried to load google web page in the first frame and the second one is my local page.

```
<cfoutput>
    <frameset rows="200,*">
        <frame src="https://www.google.co.in" ></frame>
        <frame src="test2.cfm" ></frame>
    </frameset>
</cfoutput>
```

If I try to run in "Test.cfm", In console is displaying the "Cross-site origin framing" error.

Comment: When I googled `Cross-site origin framing`, like you should have done, the word `javascript` showed up a lot.

Comment: Yes the JavaScript has few solution by HTTP or set header, but I want to run by ColdFusion(cfheader, cfcontent)

Comment: Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Simple: don't try to frame google's site in your own site.

Cross-site origin framing is an error because Google/your browser won't let you frame a site on another domain (another origin) in your own site.[1]

So don't do it and look for another way to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

[1] Framing another site in your own site is the basis of many security attacks, among which clickjacking. See for example [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) on mozilla describing the same-origin policy.